# Is MFi required if I am using "Lightning to USB Camera Adapter" with external USB device

Tags: ios, mfi

I have my developed external device which I can connect with linux PC using USB port. Now I want to develop an iOS application that communicates with this device to read/write some data. I am planning to use "Lightning to USB Camera Adapter" and EA Framework to connect to external device. Do I need MFi for this purpose?

If this is not the right way, what should i use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

A device that connect to the adapter is not MFi. You need the MFi Program only if your device is directly connected with the lightning/30-Pin port. And about software that communicates with MFi accessories, the FAQ of Apple answers :

> I want to develop an iOS app that communicates with an MFi accessory. Do I need to join the  MFi Program?
>
> No. iOS app developers do not need to join the MFi Program. Everything app developers need  is in the External Accessory Framework, which is provided in the iOS SDK. To access the iOS  SDK, please join the iOS Developer Program: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/.